# WP Как не выводить ссылку wp_get_archives на посты в текущем месяце?

Tags: php, wordpress

Подскажите, есть ли в WordPress некий фильтр который запрещает вывод текущего месяца в архиве [wp_get_archives](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_archives/)

```
<ul class="cat_block__list active">
  <?php
   $args = array();
   wp_get_archives( $args ); ?>
</ul>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

как сделать так что б текущий месяц (в данном случае Октябрь) пропускался, ну или что б он был не ссылкой а к примеру обернут в тег span ?

Answer (score 0):

Используйте хуки [getarchives_where](https://wp-kama.ru/hook/getarchives_where), [getarchives_join](https://wp-kama.ru/hook/getarchives_join)

Конкретно для Вашей задачи можно ограничить посты, исключив текущий месяц через хук getarchives_where

```
function customarchives_where( $where ) {

    global $wpdb;
    
    return $where .' AND '.$wpdb->posts.'.post_date < DATE_ADD(CURDATE(),interval -DAY(CURDATE())+1 DAY)'; 

}

add_filter( 'getarchives_where', 'customarchives_where' );
```

Comment: чет не понимаю, это мне инициализировать данный фильтр перед функцией надо ?  Просто через echo мне 1 отдает

Comment: @BlackStar1991 в functions.php . этот фильтр уже вызывается внутри функции wp_get_archives

Comment: @BlackStar1991 https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.9.2/src/wp-includes/general-template.php#L1749

Comment: Что-то не помогло, вызвал в function.php файле, но wp_get_archives свою работу не поменял / Все так же продолжает выдавать текущий месяц архива

Comment: @BlackStar1991 посмотрите в плагине query-monitor какой запрос сформировался